# DropDownList SelectedValue is Invalid Because it does not Exist in the List of Items

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I have the following asp.net DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsRole"
        DataTextField="RoleCode" DataValueField="ID" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11px"
        ForeColor="#2D2D2D" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="120px" CssClass="selectedRole"
        OnDataBound="ddlEntity_DataBound" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--- Select ---</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsRole" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetList" TypeName="Roles"
     OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I get the "SelectedValue is Invalid Because it does not Exist in the List of Items" error, stating 'value' is incorrect. The ID I'm referencing is 1 and it definitely exists in the DB where I'm calling from.

I've tried solutions to this problem as cited on the internet and other forums, but I still get the same error. I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that my SelectedValue starts off at -1?

Any suggestions?

Comment: When do you set the selected value? Is before databinding or after?

Answer (score -2):

I decided to do so to "Select" was the first line in the transmitted data set. You can do it with UNION in MSSQL.

Request this has turned out like this:

```
SELECT '-1' AS id, 'Select' AS name UNION ALL SELECT id, name FROM users
```

Must give a column alias, or DropDownList simply does not understand where the id, and where the name

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="MainCat" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id">
 </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1%>" 
             SelectCommand="SELECT id,name FROM users">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I need to do the same suit

Comment: We shouldn't do this union, this should be handled by ASP .Net, not SQL. The error is from ASP .Net so ASP .Net should fix it.